# i want to in main to call a class inside other class in c++, but i couldnt do it

Tags: c++, struct, linked-list, structure, singly-linked-list

```
class linkedlist{
     class listNode{
          int data;
          listNode* next;
            void listNode(int data,listNode* next){
            this->data=data;
            this->next=next;
        }
};

int main(){
  // in here I want to creat a listnode, but i dont know how to do it

  insert(listNode,5);
}
```

I need to call the listnode in `main()` function, I know I can use `linkedlist list;` and then `list.listNode`, but I need a node in order to fill in the `insert()` function.

Comment: Please make a [mre], including a detailed description of misbehaviour, full verbatim quotes of any error or warning you might get (as text).

Comment: "_i know i can use linkedlist list; and then list.listNode_" Did you try it? If you did, you would know, that it wouldn't work either.

Comment: The nested class is part of the outer class so you need a bit more scope resolution, `linkedlist::listNode`, to correctly identify the nested class. You also need to sort out the naming of the `listNode` function. Is it supposed to be a constructor? And when you call it, you need to provide parameters. I strongly recommend consulting [a good set of reference materials](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/388242/the-definitive-c-book-guide-and-list). C++ is not a good language to try to learn by Internet or trial and error.

Comment: i was asked by my constructor doing like this.  a linkedlist class {and a listnode class and a constructLL(..)}  , and int the main function  i need to creat a listhead, and constructLL(listhead)

Answer (score 1):

You can simply create a listNode variable like below

```
int main(){
linkedlist::listNode aNode(5, NULL);
// or
linkedlist::listNode *pNode = new linkenlist::listNode(5,NULL);
....
```

}

Comment: thanks, that help me a lot, but I have one thing left, i use "linkedlist:: listNode listHead(5,null) in main class, and now ,i want to insert(listHead,10), so what I wrote is  void insert(listNode* listHead,int n), but it says insert was not declared, I know now listNode* listHead might be wrong, but i dont know how to fix it

Comment: You can define insert function like void insert(linkedlist::listNode *listHead, int n)
{
    // find last node of list
    linkedlist::listNode *lastNode = listHead; 
    while (lastNode->next != null)
      lastNode = lastNode->next;
    
    // append new node to end of list
    lastNode->next = new linkedlist:: listNode(n, NULL);
}

Comment: i tried this way, it still says insert was not declared, the insert function is inside the linkedlist class

Comment: You can move it to out of class than you can use it. The answer given by @jul3x is more convenient and complete solution.

Comment: well, I cant. My professor required sheet said the insert has to be inside linkedlist class

Comment: so look at @jul3x solution given below. Isnt it suitable for you?

Comment: I dont think I can do that way, because the insert function has to be like insert(listHead,number)

Comment: add this method to linkedlist class  void insert(listNode* listHead, int number) {
        linkedList::listNode newNode = new linkedList::listNode(number);
        newNode->next = listHead->next;
        listHead->next = newNode;
    }

Comment: newNode->next won't pass it, and the listhead in main class is linkedlist:: listnode listhead, if we use it to insert(listhead,5), we cannot just set insert(listNode* listhead  or linkedlist:: listNode listhead)

Comment: sorry this should be like that void insert(linkedList::listNode* listHead, int number)

Comment: i just post my code here and my professor reqiurement, the only problem is still the constructLL in main function, keep saying constructLL is could not be resolved

Comment: You need a linkedlist instance. in main function uncomment linkedlist list; than use list.constructLL().

Answer (score 0):

`listNode` is a class defined inside `linkedList` class. This means that you need to enter appropriate namespace before usage of described symbol. Also, you need to call constructor of your desired class. To be honest, you better should read some C++ tutorial, because your example has more errors.

Valid *`very simple`* implementation would be:

```
#include <iostream>

class linkedList {
public:
    class listNode {
    public:
        int data;
        listNode* next;

        listNode(int data_) : data(data_), next(nullptr) {}
    };

    linkedList() : head(nullptr), tail(nullptr) {}

    void insert(listNode* new_node) {
        if (head == tail && tail == nullptr) {
            head = tail = new_node;
        }
        else {
            tail->next = new_node;
            tail = new_node;
        }
    }

    listNode* getFront() { return head; };

    listNode* getBack() { return tail; };

    listNode* head;
    listNode* tail;
};

int main(){
    linkedList list;
    list.insert(new linkedList::listNode(5));
    list.insert(new linkedList::listNode(6));
    list.insert(new linkedList::listNode(7));

    std::cout << list.getFront()->data << std::endl; // 5
    std::cout << list.getBack()->data << std::endl;  // 7
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: `list.insert(linkedlist::listNode(5));` won't compile because `insert()` is expecting a `listNode*` pointer but you are giving it a `listNode` instance instead. You would need to use `list.insert(new linkedlist::listNode(5));` , but now you have to deal with proper dynamic memory management, the Rule of 3/5/0, etc. `insert()` should take just an `int` as input and create a new node for it, the caller should not be creating nodes directly

Comment: Yeah, I just modified code. But for memory management - if list is created like this - it does not matter - let the OS take care of cleaning up.

Comment: well, thanks for correct me, but the point i confused is my instructor ask me to get something like this.   A linkedlist class { a listNode class { data,next} and constructLL(listNode* listHead)} which here is ok for me, but in main function, she ask me,get a new listnode which is listHead,and using the function constructLL(listHead); which is confused me

Answer (score 0):

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/uzSxM.png)

```
enter code here
class linkedlist{
public:
class listNode{
public:
        int data;
        listNode* next;
        listNode(int data,listNode* next){
            this->data=data;
            this->next=next;
        }
        void printNode(listNode* node,ofstream& outFile){
            outFile<<"( "<<node->data<<","<<node<<","<<node->next<<","<<node->next- 
 >data<<")"<<endl;
        }
};
//  listNode* listHead;
//  listNode* listHead(){
//      return new listNode(-9999,NULL);
//  }
listNode* findSpot(listNode* listHead,listNode* newNode){
    listNode* spot=listHead;
    while(spot->next!=NULL && spot->next->data<newNode->data)
        spot=spot->next;
    return spot;
}
void listInsert(listNode* listHead,listNode* newNode){
    listNode* spot=findSpot(listHead,newNode);
    newNode->next=spot->next;
    spot->next=newNode;
}
void printList(listNode* listHead,ofstream& outFile){
    listNode* c=listHead;
    outFile<<"listHead -> ";
    while(c->next!=NULL){
        outFile<<"( "<<c->data<<","<<c<<","<<c->next<<","<<c->next->data<<") -> ";
        c=c->next;
    }
    outFile<<" NULL "<<endl;
}
void constructLL(linkedlist::listNode* listHead,ifstream& inFile,ofstream& outFile2){
    int a;
    cout<<listHead->data<<endl;
    while(inFile>>a){
        listNode* newNode=new listNode(a,NULL);
        listInsert(listHead,newNode);
        printList(listHead,outFile2);
    }
}
listNode* findMiddleNode(listNode* listHead,ofstream& outFile2){
    listNode* walk1=listHead;
    listNode* walk2=listHead;
    listHead->printNode(walk1, outFile2);
    while(walk2!=NULL && walk2->next!=NULL){
        walk1=walk1->next;
        walk2=walk2->next->next;
    }
    return walk1;
}
};
int main(int argc ,char* argv[]) {
   ifstream inFile(argv[1]);
   ofstream outFile1(argv[2]);
    ofstream outFile2(argv[3]);
//  linkedlist list;
//  list.listHead();
cout<<"123";
linkedlist:: listNode listHead(-9999,NULL);
//  list.sethead(-9999);
//  listHead=new listNode(-9999,NULL);
 //     cout<<list.gethead();
constructLL(listHead,inFile,outFile2);
//  printList(listHead,outFile1);
//  listNode* middleNode=findMiddleNode(listHead,outFile2);
//  listHead->printNode(middleNode,outFile1);
inFile.close();
outFile1.close();
outFile2.close();
return 0;
}
```